# Flex 4 app, coldfusion help

Tags: actionscript-3, coldfusion, flex4, server-side

I have some* experience using the flex framework for building web apps.

But I have no experience with server side languages, I have heard the saying "choose one and stick to it" several times in reference to programming.

I have chosen coldfusion.

Now I have no clue what to do or where to start.

Now to the details:

It will be a site for food showcases. Food menus sorted by cultural origin, vegetarian or meat kind, etc. Things like that.

I intend to build a web site that enables subscriptions, and keeps them updated whenever updates are made. And a commenting system to encourage user feedback.
And I would like the site to have a database of food items (as mentioned earlier); from my research coldfusion will enable me to do this.

I would like resources that I could go to, and do more research myself. 
And all recommendations that can be provided.

Whether you think I dont need coldfusion, and if I can get this done with just flex and as3.

I appreciate all feedback, thanks for taking the time to read and respond.
* = not much experience, still a "beginner"

Comment: Do you already have a webhost that support coldfusion within your budget ?

Comment: No I have not. But I know of hosts that support it. I want to learn the language before going out and buying hosting space

Comment: check which version they support!  Many of them are still stuck at CF7!  And share hosting might not have flex endpoint enabled for you.. since you tagged Flex

Comment: Thanks Henry, do you know of any servers supporting the most recent versions of flex and coldfusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best place for you to start would be the "CFWACK" (ColdFusion Web Application Construction Kit) series of books. Pick the series specific to the version of ColdFusion you have available to you -- CF9 is relatively new to market, and the books are available, but a majority of shared (e.g. cheaper) hosts still use a previous version. Find out what version you will be working with, and then get the books.

- **ColdFusion 9**:

  - [Volume 1: Getting Started](http://amzn.com/032166034X)
  - [Volume 2: Application Development](http://amzn.com/0321679199)
  - [Volume 3: Advanced Application Development](http://amzn.com/0321679202)
- **ColdFusion 8**:

  - [Volume 1: Getting Started](http://amzn.com/032151548X)
  - [Volume 2: Application Development](http://amzn.com/0321515463)
  - [Volume 3: Advanced Application Development](http://amzn.com/0321515471)

For prior versions, just search Amazon for "ColdFusion {version} Web Application Construction Kit"

That is, by and large, the canonical reference for learning ColdFusion. It is updated for each new version of ColdFusion, by some of the biggest names and most thorough developers in the CF Community.

Once you've learned any given version, it's relatively easy to catch up with a newer version by reading the release notes for that version. ColdFusion documentation is traditionally very thorough, which is amazing.

Once you've read the CFWACK books, and you're ready to start day-to-day developer life, (if this is your sort of thing) there is a huge community of ColdFusion developer bloggers, as well as on twitter. Just because of ubiquity and continuous flow of content, I would recommend you start with [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com) and [Ray Camden](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com)'s blogs.

Comment: Thanks alot Adam, I believe this is what I am looking for. I appreciate it.
Are you an experienced coldfusion programmer?

if so, do you have experience with as3 and flex? Do they work with coldfusion well?

Comment: Yes, I am an experienced ColdFusion developer. I have somewhat recently learned Flex and AS3, and they do work quite well together.

Answer (score 2):

I'll ditto the recommendation for CFWACK, but as one of the authors I'm a bit biased. One point of clarification. The books are NOT written from scratch for each new version. In cases where we can just update, we do.

Now - I definitely want to see everyone buy CFWACK - but don't forget that Adobe ships a multi-thousand page PDF for CF docs. This is a *wealth* of information that is 100% free.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will do a check on the adobe cf documentation.

Comment: I've never bought the WACK though there are 3 in our office for various versions of CF.  I see the WACK for CF9 is on O'Reilly as a rough cut only so no adding it to the bookshelf yet (same with Flex 4 training from the source, that's the one I'm waiting on).

Comment: Travis, book one should be available now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about rewrites Ray, I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The best resources:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/index.html

http://www.carehart.org/ugtv/

Keep yourself in the loop:

http://twitter.com/danshort/coldfusion

http://feeds.adobe.com/

If you're stuck with some CF questions, post up here or ask one of them:

http://www.bennadel.com/ask-ben/ask-ben-nadel.htm

http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/contact.cfm

Comment: Thanks for the links Henry, will be sure to put them to use.